# Why can't I see the Controllers folder within my deployed MVC web app directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controllers

I have recently purchased a shared web hosting package, provided by GoDaddy, and deployed my own MVC web application to it.

My problem is that, when on the control panel (Plesk) provided by the host, I can't find the Controllers folder that contains all the behind code.

***Is there a reason for this folder being hidden?***

I'm guessing it's because the files within this folder are being used by the server all the time and can't be accessed/changed incase it f--ks everything up... But I am not sure about it because I am quite new to web hosting.

Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to access that folder? Controllers are compiled to the web app's dll. There shouldn't be anything to put in this folder after deployment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was just curious about where the controllers went to... It seemed like the web app was working like magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your cs files including controllers will be compiled into DLL files. Please open "bin" directory to find all your DLLs.

Comment: Exception - if they happen to also be using `App_Code` - those `.cs` files would be deployed and compiled later.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy, u ll not get controller, because it contains c# code which changed to dll available inside bin folder.

Not Only Controller, the other folders which are having C# code like "App_Start"...and etc...will be changed to dll and will be available inside bin folder.

In the case of Model/s, if you are using Entity framework, then, the .edmx file will be available inside the Model folder.

Comment: That should be a comment

Comment: And the other answer >.<

Comment: @Luke the other answer at least is understandable, and was posted earlier. Neither can be considered a good answer.

Comment: Also, another question; can these files be edited? I'm gonna go ahead and guess that they can't...

Comment: @JohnSmith - you mean you want to edit  .dll file ;)

Answer (score 0):

All your Business logics including controllers, models and core etc are converted to dll and by Assembly name dll is created in bin (released or debug folder)